# Is there a bug in the way answers are sorted?

Tags: support, answers

Here I have chosen to sort based on upvotes but the one with 12 shows above  the one with 53. Or am I getting something wrong ??

[image]

Here is the question I'm referring to :
[PHP remove characters after last occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746695/php-remove-characters-after-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string/16758673#16758673)

Comment: Because it is the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this question already asked ?

Comment: Why is this community so harsh, downvoting for asking a question that has not been asked ?

Comment: Where is the be nice policy ??????

Comment: Now high rep users will reply you said like something "Voting on meta is different. It just say they don't agree what you said...... bla... bla.........". But don't worry about down-votes, here their some people hobby is down voting others question and answers... Specially question asker is low rep user....

Answer (score 13):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Accepted answers are pinned to the top unless they are from the OP, then they show up in the correct vote order.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer always<sup>**1**</sup> shows at the top because it indicates that this solution was what the OP felt helped them the most at the time.

While it may have some issues overall, and this topic has been discussed at length , this is the design.

This is probably a good place to start if you were curious about past discussions:

> "Ultimately the sort order should be for one thing, and one thing only: putting things the person viewing the page in that moment is most likely to find useful.
>
> Once you've got that straight it is possible to see past the arguments that "the OP has a right to accept whatever answer they feel best answers their question". Of course they do, but that is entirely separate to everyone else's sort order, which should be for their benefit, not the question OPs."
>   -[Richard Tingle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226494/178816)

> "Does this mean the 'accepted answer' mechanism is faulty? No. It seems to work in the vast majority of cases, and where it doesn't can be explained by statistical outliers.
>
> Should we do anything about it? **No**."
>   -[George Stocker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49682/178816)

*<sub>1. If the OP accepts their own answer then it will not be pinned to the top (thanks to @Makoto for pointing this out)</sub>*

Comment: `:%s/always/almost always`, since it doesn't apply that sort if the OP accepts their own answer.

Comment: @Makoto - edited